# Rails mailer does not send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to use rails (5.1.4) mailer, I don't receive any email like I should do. I followed the official rails guide to make it. My config/environment/development.rb :

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'username@gmail.com',
    password:             'app-password-from-google',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true 
  }
```

With this config I made a new mailer in mailers/appointement_mailer.rb :

```
class AppointementMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => "username@gmail.com"

  def appointement_information(user_email, data)
    @email = user_email
    @body = data
    mail(:to => "username@gmail.com", :subject => "xxx")
  end
end
```

This mailer is triggered by a form controlled by a controller, it is located under controllers/contacts_controller.rb :

```
      def new

      end

      def create
        @appointement = appointement_params
        AppointementMailer.appointement_information(@appointement['email'], @appointement['body'])
        flash[:notice] = "Some message"
        redirect_to articles_path
      end

      private
      def appointement_params
        params.require('appointement').permit(:email, :body)
      end
```

The form correctly display the flash "Some Message" and no error is written in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `deliver_now` on your call to the mailer.

```
AppointementMailer.appointement_information(@appointement['email'], @appointement['body']).deliver_now
```

Comment: Off topic, but the correct spelling for that word is appointment, just a friendly FYI!